# Input type number doesn't work on Window Surface Tablet

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, input, tablet

i've noticed that if we try to open https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

in Chrome on Windows Surface Tablet it will behave as in desktop browser.
I mean on Tablet(mobile) device if i tap on `<input type="number">` than Chrome will show number keyboard. But on Surface Chrome will show text keyboard.

> In addition, mobile browsers further help with the user experience by
>   showing a special keyboard more suited for entering numbers when the
>   user tries to enter a value.
>    [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Is there a way how to force Chrome on Windows Surface to behave as mobile browser? At least for number field?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows Surface with Chrome to test on, but try

```
 <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text" name="something">
```

This should still force the browser to open the number keypad